# Trying to Set weight through Android code

Tags: android

Hi guys I am new to Stack and also Android. I have run in to an issue with weight. I am not sure what i am missing as I have tried multiple different ways and none seem to work or i am missing something. Any help would be appreciated, code below

```
GridLayout poster_grid = findViewById(R.id.poster_grid);

    for (int i = 0; i < final_image_url.size(); i++) {
        String nameCut = final_image_url.get(i);
        final String GAME_ID = gameId.get(i);
        ImageButton posters = new ImageButton(this);
        ****LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                2);****
        params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
        posters.setLayoutParams(params);
        posters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent info_activity = new Intent(Poster_Activity.this, Info_Activity.class);
                info_activity.putExtra("game_id", GAME_ID);
                startActivity(info_activity);
            }
        });

        Picasso.get()
                .load("http:" + nameCut)
                //.resize(430, 430)
                .into(posters);
        poster_grid.addView(posters);
    }
```

Comment: GridLayout isn't a LinearLayout. You can't use LinearLayout.LayoutParams. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Additionally you would *never* add views to a gridview.  GridViews use adapters.  Adding views to it will screw things up.

Comment: And GridViews do not respect weight.

Comment: @TheWanderer I am trying to dynamically set buttons with images, so it grows to the screen size of the device, but i would like it to be in 3 columns.

Comment: @GabeSechan this is a GridLayout not View.

Comment: @MikeDonati set the GridLayout width to match_parent then.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you for the help.